# Why is "What is the best way...." like title allowed?

Tags: discussion

As we know, opinion based questions are not allowed here, if the titles appears words like "What is the best way..." There will be a warning box come out.

But the question is, why can the question can still be submitted? Why don't ban the titles automatically?? When is such title on topic?

Comment: because often times they're simply asking for a solution, but they want it to be the "best" solution. removing the "best" requirement would generally make it not opinion-based, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a heuristic. A question title isn't inherently subjective just because it contains the word "best", even if it's likely to be. Besides, even if you did restrict it you'd just end up with titles like

> What is the b.est way...

or

> What is the b3st way...

or

> What is the goodest way...

which defeats the entire point of restricting submissions.

You can count on the community to close subjective questions that do end up posted. If anything they're much more reliable than the quality filter for questions like these.

Answer (score 1):

Most of "best way" questions are requests for code that provides any semi-reasonable way. The behavior is similar to all kinds of "thank you" text you can find in posts - some detected, but most just left for community to cleanup from reasonable questions. Trying to automatically catch all possible variations of "best" is not exactly easy and so far handled fine by community as mentioned in [BoltClock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308150/477420).

In rare cases when such question turns out to be good fit for SO it is trivial to edit title into something that describes the problem.

Additionally any phrase similar to "best way" in title/body gives good indication that post is likely of low quality - as poster has no idea what they need. On other hand "better" likely indicates effort (as one has to show what to compare to and in what sense it need to be improved). So "best way" in title can be used to quickly triage question.